# Multiple GET requests for the same CSS file in Firefox Inspector

Tags: html

There is only one place in my page that links to this css file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://domain.com/css/23beac5f7ba9d3e94ba463892e86b2ff.0.1.css">
```

However, when viewing the network tab in Firefox's inspector, it is counting two requests for this file (which exists), and also counting the size of the css file twice in the total size of all files requested.

[image: Two CSS requests]

The request at the end in this screenshot loads last, and takes a while longer than the rest of the requests to appear. The only thing I notice different about the two is that the last one under "Cause" has a "JS" symbol next to where it says "stylesheet". I do not know what that means or why it's there.

Any suggestions as to what might be causing my css file to load twice like this?

Comment: That looks like a webpackish sort of generated CSS file name; is this perhaps a React app that has a `require` (or `import`) of CSS which is causing it to be injected in the page a second time?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Might be this bug : https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1306892

If you opened the Inspector or Style Editor before opening the Network Monitor, it triggers additional requests to CSS files that unfortunately show up in your requests list.

To verify this:

- select Net Monitor in FF Devtools
- close devtools
- reload your site
- open devtools

Devtools should open on the Net Monitor tab directly and you should not see any duplicate request.

Comment: That's exactly what it was. Genius! Thank you so much

Comment: Whut?! I've just spend 4hrs trying to debug this fuckDMQSkdlqcsqkmdmQl. Should've come and search SO sooner :|

Answer (score 2):

The second request was caused by a javascript file. According to [Mozilla's Developer Tools docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Network_Monitor#Cause_column):

> When a request was triggered by JavaScript, a small JS icon is shown to the left of the entry in the Cause column. Hovering over this displays a popup containing the stack trace for the request, to provide more clues as to why a request happened.

Try hovering over the JS icon to get more info on what javascript file made the second call.

Update: You can also try viewing the page in Chrome. The network tab in Chrome's Developer Tools column has an "Initiator" column that shows which file initiated the call.

Comment: What's strange is I completely removed all links to all of my .js files, and it still shows. There are literally no .js files being included or used on the page, and yet this still shows. I can't tell by hovering over the icon what is causing it.

Comment: Do you have Chrome available? That might give additional helpful info.

Comment: I have Safari, and I looked at it using Safari's developer tools, and it appears to only be loading once.

Comment: Interestingly, this still happen in 2017